# Extract timestamp from filename and sort

Tags: sorting, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to look through each item in a folder and add each item to an array sorted by the datestamp in the filename.

For example, I have three files:

- myfile_20150813_040949.txt
- myfile_20150812_030949.txt
- myfile_20150812_010949.txt

I'm not sure how to parse out the time from each and add them to an array in ascending order. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just for clarification, are you looking to add each file to an array and sort by the parsed timestamp?

Comment: Is there something you have tried? Even pseudo code is better than nothing. Does "myfile" ever contain underscores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are looking to sort the files by the parsed timestamp that is pulled from the file name with this example. It may not the be the best RegEx approach, but it works in testing.

```
#RegEx pattern to parse the timestamps
$Pattern = '.*_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\.txt'
$List = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$Temp = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
Get-ChildItem | ForEach {
    #Make sure the file matches the pattern
    If ($_.Name -match $Pattern) {
        Write-Verbose "Add $($_.Name)" -Verbose
        $Date = $Matches[2],$Matches[3],$Matches[1] -join '/'
        $Time = $Matches[4..6] -join ':'
        [void]$Temp.Add(
            (New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                Date =[datetime]"$($Date) $($Time)"
                File = $_
            }
        ))
    }
}
#Sort the files by the parsed timestamp and add to the main list
$List.AddRange(@($Temp | Sort Date | Select -Expand File))
#Clear out the temp collection
$Temp.Clear()
#Display the results
$List
```

Comment: That's awkward. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You better to use `[DateTime]"$($Date) $($Time)"` instead of `Get-Date "$($Date) $($Time)"`. `Get-Date` cmdlet use current culture when convert from string to `DateTime`, while `[DateTime]` cast use invariant culture. For example, for me `Get-Date '04/09/2015'` return September 4, 2015; but `[DateTime]'04/09/2015'` return April 9, 2015.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't output anything? Where is $Items supposed to be used?

Comment: You can ignore `$Items` as it was just used for testing. I updated the code to include some verbose output to see if the RegEx is actually working against your file names

Comment: One more question - sorry - how do I populate the array to use the code you provided? Like if I want to do this:

   $myFiles = @()

   foreach($file in 'C:\Temp') 
   {
      $myFiles += $File.name
   }

Comment: `$List` is the array that has been created in the script as a `System.Collections.ArrayList`. In this instance I use .`.AddRange()` to add all of the items collected in the `$Temp` collection. If you want to add more things to it, you can use `.Add()`.

Comment: Oh geez, nevermind :) I just needed to add the folder path after GetChild_Item...

Answer (score 1):

What you could be doing for this is using the string method `.Split()` with the `[datetime]` method of `TryParseExact()`. Go though each file and add a property for the "FromFileDate" and then sort on that.

```
$path = "C:\temp"
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.txt" -Path $path | ForEach-Object{
    $date = ($_.BaseName).Split("_",2)[1]
    $result = New-Object DateTime
    if([datetime]::TryParseExact($date,"yyyyMMdd_hhmmss",[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,[System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,[ref]$result)){
        # This is a good date
        Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FromFileDate" -Value $result -PassThru
    } Else {
        # Could not parse date from filename
        Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FromFileDate" -Value "Could not Parse" -PassThru
    }
} | Select-Object Name,fromfiledate | Sort-Object fromfiledate
```

We take the basename of the each text file and split it into 2 parts from the first underscore. Using `TryParseExact` we then attempt to convert the "date" string to the format of "yyyyMMdd_hhmmss". Since we use `TryParseExact` if we have trouble parsing the date then the code will continue.

**Sample Output**

```
Name                       FromFileDate        
----                       ------------        
myfile_20150812_030949.txt 8/12/2015 3:09:49 AM
myfile_20150813_040949.txt 8/13/2015 4:09:49 AM
files.txt                  Could not Parse
```

If you didn't want the erroneous data in the output a simple `Where-Object{$_.fromfiledate -is [datetime]}` would remove those entries.

Comment: I'm getting an error, "Cannot find an overload for "TryParseExact" and the argument count: "5"". I am using PS ver 2.0...is that function for versions 3.0+?

Comment: @AaronJohnsen Will have to double check.